# Why does input from multiple Sockets not update UI properly?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

Notebook code: http://pastebin.com/hNgjr4QY , Server code: http://pastebin.com/J5hnz2mu

I am mostly interesested in notebook part of code:

```
private class ClientHandler implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
        String message = null;

        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (!message.equals(""))
                {
                    textArea.setText(message);
                    textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and

```
public void run()
    {
        String message = null;

        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                for (ComputerConnections ccc: comCon)
                {
                    ccc.printWriter.println(message);
                    ccc.printWriter.flush();
                }
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

well, the point of the program is to allow as many users to connect, and after they can all write in THE SAME notepad, and the program should update it accordingly, well and it seems it is behaving weird. At first it updates fine, but then it just suddenly stops, and works every few key pressess!

Comment: You'll have to redesign the server. If one connection receives a line, it currently sends it to all connected clients. There is nothing to avoid a thread switch to another connection, which will read a line and send it to all connected clients. Result: garbled and different sequence of text for the clients.

Comment: I don't quite get it, I am still new to Java and grasping for air... As I see the client is supposed to send to server, and then the server to all avaible clients. But yes, it is all getting confused... What do you mean with "There is nothing to avoid a thread switch to another connection, which will read a line and send it to all connected clients."

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is a UI problem and not a socket problem you are describing (Although there are other problems with this code).  This would be easy to figure out, just put some `System.out.println()` debug lines instead of the UI writes.

If that's the case, you should use the EDT thread so make changes to GUI so that the only thread that makes changes to GUIs is that one and that one alone to avoid interference, like so

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( 
        new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                textArea.setText(message);
            }
        }
    );
```

UIs are famously hard to make multi-threaded so the best way around this is to queue up updates that are handled by one UI thread (in Javas case, the [EDT - Event Dispatch Thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread)).

Comment: This problem of threads is worse because the earlier documentation of setText documentation that it was thread safe, but it was later removed because it was never thread-safe. This is a common pitfall for people who learned java in the past

Comment: Good idea, but you may create many objects.  One for each socket update, so, IMHO, the SwingWorker would be better approach.

Comment: `SwingWorker` is normally used in background tasks to avoid freezing the UI.  UI updates should generally be dispatched onto the EDT, which `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is used for.
The only reason I would use `SwingWorker` in this case is if I was buffering the input somehow and updating the UI periodically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for this kind of processing.

Let all sockets `publish` the data, and then update the GUI in the `process` method.